# Uploading image through Selenium in Alibaba.com search bar

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload

I am trying to upload image for www.alibaba.com image search through send_keys. I want to do it in headless browser so, Autoit approach will not work.

Upload Button is clickable but enable to take send_keys data.

```
    url =  'https://www.alibaba.com/'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds
    browser.get(url)
    element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ui-searchbar-imgsearch-icon")
    element.click()
    element2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("upload-btn")
    path = "filepath"
    element2.send_keys(path)
```

I am getting the message **ElementNotInteractableException**

[Upload Button DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECpPw.jpg)

Is there any other way of uploading image without the opening of filesystem popup?

Comment: you can not upload image using selenium, use sikuli with selenium to upload image. (link)https://www.guru99.com/sikuli-tutorial.html

Comment: This is false, you can upload an image using Selenium. ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send keys to the `input` with `type='file'` element, not the `Upload Image` button. The `input` is also hidden, so you will need to execute Javascript to reveal it before you can send keys:

```
url =  'https://www.alibaba.com/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds
browser.get(url)
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("ui-searchbar-imgsearch-icon")
element.click()

input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")

# reveal the input element
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", input)

# send keys for file path to input element
input.send_keys(path)
```

Comment: @MuaazTariq Glad to hear it -- if this answer was helpful, feel free to mark as the solution to your problem so that other users can see that it worked for you.